# CSS page-break-after for background image

Tags: css

Is there any way to use CSS property of page break with background image?

```
page-break-after:always;
```

I m using repeat background image and when writing a print stylesheet, is there a way to ensure that background image is always only on a single page, now the background image is end up at the bottom of the page and get split.

Comment: use a block-level element, the background of an element has nothing to do with how the element is positioned? Please explain what you are trying to do

Comment: I m using repeat background image and when writing a print stylesheet, is there a way to ensure that  background image is always only on a single page, now the background image is end up at the bottom of the page and get split.